# The named parameter 'topLeft' isn't defined.- flutter

Tags: flutter

getting those errors >>

> The named parameter 'topLeft' isn't defined.
>
> The named parameter 'topRight' isn't defined.
>
> The getter 'ac_unit' isn't defined for the type 'Icon'.
>
> The getter 'accessibility_new' isn't defined for the type 'Icon'.
>
> The getter 'assesment' isn't defined for the type 'Icon'
>
> The name '_selectedItem' is already defined.

how to correct these errors

[image]

```
void _onButtonPressed() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
                   child:_buildBottomNavigationMenu() ,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                topLeft:const Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: const Radius.circular(10)
            ),
          );
        });
  }

      Column _buildBottomNavigationMenu() {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icon.ac_unit),
              title: Text('Cooling'),
              onTap: () => _selectedItem,
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icon.accessibility_new),
              title: Text('People'),
              onTap: () => _selectedItem,
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icon.assesment),
              title: Text('Status'),
              onTap: () => _selectedItem,
            ),
          ],
        );
      }


  void _selectedItem (String name){
    Navigator.pop(context);
    setState(() {
      _selectedItem = name;
    });
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to add specific radius in container decoration [reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BorderRadius/BorderRadius.only.html)

```
Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
          );
```

Also you added `Icon.ac_unit` but you should use `Icons.ac_unit` .

Answer (score 0):

That means that property not available for decorationbox widget
see here :https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html

and for icon it will be Icons.{icon-name}

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
void _onButtonPressed() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
                   child:_buildBottomNavigationMenu() ,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(  // updated code here
                  topLeft: const Radius.circular(10),
                  topRight: const Radius.circular(10)
                  bottomLeft: Radius.zero,
                  bottomRight: Radius.zero,
    ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

      Column _buildBottomNavigationMenu() {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit), // updated Icon to Icons
              title: Text('Cooling'),
              onTap: () => _selectedItem,
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.accessibility_new),
              title: Text('People'),
              onTap: () => _selectedItem,
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.assesment),
              title: Text('Status'),
              onTap: () => _selectedItem,
            ),
          ],
        );
      }


  void _selectedItem (String name){
    Navigator.pop(context);
    setState(() {
      _selectedItem = name;
    });
  }


}
```

Comment: tysm. it works. but one error>>> The name '_selectedItem' is already defined.

Comment: it should be _selectItem  problem solved